# Handle very large json schema in firefox that takes more then 20 seconds to render

Tags: javascript, json, firefox, jsonschema

I have a json schema of size 20MB. When its loaded in google chrome its makes approximate 20 seconds to render view. Although when I load it in **firefox**, its fails.

On google, I find there is script execution time limit 10 seconds. When I set this to 20-25 seconds. Its execute perfectly in firefox.

Is there any alternative of above to execute java-scripts in firefox that takes more than 10 seconds. As I can't set **dom.max_script_run_time** on every machine.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider streaming that JSON data instead of loading it all at once in your app since it's 20 megs. I haven't used it yet but there is a library, [Oboe.js](http://oboejs.com/examples) which can parse that JSON data while it's still loading and you can use callbacks to process when you start receiving bits of finished JSON. This is not a really fast solution but I think would be the easiest approach.